# Amazon S3 Uploads From GWT App

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

How would I go about uploading files to S3 from a Google Web Toolkit page? Ideally, it would all be done asynchronously, allowing me to display a progress bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't help you with the GWT specifics, but as for the S3 side, you should:

1. download the Java Developer kit from the Amazon S3 site,
2. write the Java code to store files there from your server-side application (making sure you can test that code separately)
3. Make your client GWT code upload the files to your server and provide progress for upload
4. Make your server call your S3 interface with the uploaded file (progress here might not be unless you do call the AMAZON put as a REST call where you can count the bytes your are sending)
5. provide confirmation of successful store back to your user (or error)

Hope that helps.